# Tensorflow predict more than one tag

Tags: python, tags, tensorflow, tagging, photo-tagging

I am very new to TensorFlow as well as stackoverflow. I am working on a project in which I'm supposed to recommend 5 most suitable tags for a photo. Tensorflow gives you a prediction value for every tag you've trained the final layer for & in that too it aims to find the one with an accuracy of more than 0.5 & other tags end up having values less than 0.1. **But how do I find out if more than 1 tag come out to be the most relevant tags?**
e.g. For an image of a red bird, TF (Tensorflow) gives me bird as the best tag & red as the second best tag, although both are equally relevant.

My question is that **how can I make TF give equal value to more than 1 tag if they are relevant enough? (And if not same, very near numbers would do it for me.) Also, is there a way that I can get the output of these tags & their corresponding values in a .txt file?** (The last part of the question has been asked previously too, but it remains unanswered so I thought I would include it as a part of my question)

The code of my label_image.py is the same as given in tutorial - TensorFlow for poets. Here is the code for it,

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    image_path = sys.argv[1]

    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

    label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
               in tf.gfile.GFile("/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt")]

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                 {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

        top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I find out if more than 1 tag come out to be the most relevant tags?

If you look at the output in the final layer of your network, supposing you use a softmax layer, you should have different values in each label, indicating the **confidence** of that label being the right one. As a result, this score **is essentially the relevance** of the corresponding label.

#### Is there a way that I can get the output of these tags & their corresponding values in a .txt file?

Yes, we basically `eval()` the score and use `f.write(content)` to write it to a text file.

A very simple code block:

```
scores = tf.eval(test_confidence, feed_dict={....})
with open("output.txt", "wb") as f:
    for score in scores:
        f.write(score+'\n')
```

Comment: Sorry for asking a stupid question but where do I add the code snippet you've given in my code? I would appreciate it if you could just show me the correct placement of your code snippet in my code as I'm pretty much new to TF as well as python.

Comment: Well, it depends on your plan of when to store those scores. If I may assume you only store the scores at the end of the training session, you may put the code snippet at the end of your code. My code is only for demonstration purpose but you get idea: replace the `test_confidence` with what you want to `eval`; set `feed_dict` the training data you have etc.